# Stream html5 camera output

Tags: camera, html5-video

does anyone know how to stream html5 camera output to other users.

If that's possible should I use sockets, images and stream them to the users or other technology.

Is there any video tutorial where I can take a look about it.

Many thanks.

Comment: Will this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40045857/live-video-streaming-with-html-5

Comment: Thanks, good examples

Answer (score 0):

The two most common approaches now are most likely:

- stream from the source to a server, and allow users connect to the server to stream to their devices, typically using some form of Adaptive Bit Rate streaming protocol (ABR - basically creates multiple bit rate versions of your content and chunks them, so the client can choose the next chunk from the best bit rate for the device and current network conditions).

  - Stream peer to peer, or via a conferencing hub, using WebRTC

In general, the latter is more focused towards real time, e.g. any delay should be below the threshold which would interfere with audio and video conferences, usually less than 200ms for audio for example. To achieve this it may have to sacrifice quality sometimes, especially video quality.

There are some good WebRTC samples available online (here at the time of writing): https://webrtc.github.io/samples/